# Единственное и множественное число. Допустимы оба варианта?

Tags: грамотная-речь, единственное-множественное-число, выбор-варианта

*Я все думаю о сегодняшнем и вчерашнем **дне.***
*Я все думаю о сегодняшнем и вчерашнем **днях.***

Какой вариант предпочтительней?
(Толика иронии в заголовке со словом "число".)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С должной толикой иронии считаю, что правильно использовать единственное число существительного:
*Я всё думаю о сегодняшнем и вчерашнем **дне.***

Имя существительное, которому предшествует два или несколько определений, указывающих на разновидности предметов, ставится в форме единственного числа, если перечисляемые разновидности предметов или явлений **внутренне связаны**, например, в сочетаниях терминологического характера:
в правой и левой *руке* (половине, стороне и т. п.);
оперное и балетное *искусство*;
промышленный и аграрный *переворот*;
учащиеся среднего и старшего школьного *возраста*;
программы для восьмилетней и средней *школы* (как системы образования);
в старославянском и древнерусском книжном *языке*;
глаголы совершенного и несовершенного *вида* (действительного и страдательного *залога*, настоящего и прошедшего *времени*, изъявительного и сослагательного *наклонения*, первого и второго *спряжения* и т. п.);
существительные мужского, женского и среднего *рода* (первого и второго *склонения*, единственного и множественного ***числа***); [вот, вот она, ваша ирония!]
местоимения первого и второго *лица*;
вирусный и простой *грипп*;
головной и спинной *мозг*;
война Алой и Белой *розы*.

Его облик, скупой жест, интонации, внакладку на какой-то серо-бытовой фон, вполне создавали впечатление скептической разуверенности во *вчерашнем, сегодняшнем и завтрашнем **дне***... [Михаил Веллер. Ножик Сережи Довлатова (1997)]

Он заговорил на тему, которая, как и во время нашего разговора в 1950 году, продолжала его занимать, — о необходимости объективной оценки сил и возможностей противника, идет ли речь об истории или о *сегодняшнем и завтрашнем **дне***. [Константин Симонов. К биографии Г. К. Жукова (1968)]

[§194. Два определения при одном существительном](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL02/70091272.html)